# React ref in ref

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I use a `react-textarea-autosize` that is wrapped in a `styled-component`, like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import TextareaAutosize from 'react-textarea-autosize'

const MyTextArea = styled(TextareaAutosize)``

function Component() {
  return (
    <MyTextArea innerRef={...} />
  )
}
```

I need to get the reference for the underlying html `textarea` element. However, to get to it I need to:

- The `TextareaAutosize` component can be accessed via the `styled-components`' `innerRef` prop - `<MyTextArea innerRef={textareaResizeable => ...} />`
- The html `textarea` element can be accessed via the `react-textarea-autosize`' `inputRef` prop - `<TextareaAutosize inputRef={textarea => ...} />`

I understand these two separate steps. But how do I access the `textarea` html element directly from `MyTextArea` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1151). So, in my case the solution looked like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import TextareaAutosize from 'react-textarea-autosize'

const MyTextArea = styled(
  ({_ref, ...props}) => <TextareaAutosize inputRef={_ref} {...props} />
)``

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyTextArea innerRef={node => this.textarea = node} />
    )
  }
}
```

then use `this.textarea` wherever you need.